# explanation about samples

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

What is the difference between CSASPNETWebsite and CSASPNETFacebookApp samples?

I am new to facebook development. I want to create an external website that uses facebook login and registration. I also want that site available as a facebook app inside facebook.  I am confused regarding which sample should I use and why?

Please advise.
Pratik

Answer (score 1):

CSASPNETWebsite is for a Facebook for Websites application, also known as Facebook Connect.  These apps are hosted as standalone apps on your server (not iFrames within the Facebook chrome)

CSASPNETFacebookApp is for an "Apps on Facebook" application, also known as a Canvas Application or iFrame application.  These apps appear in iFrames on an apps.facebook.com/yourapp URL.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ for more information on what you can do with a canvas vs. connect application.

Comment: Pat, thanks for the explanation.  I am making a simple test facebook app which will just post on the user's wall. I do want to try and make this app run on an external website (outside facebook chrome). So, it should basically run within the facebook chrome and externally as well.  Which sample should I use as a starting point?

Comment: I think you should pick one approach - canvas/iframe app or standalone "connect" app.  I'm not sure it works very well trying to do both with one app.  It is easiest and has the fewest policy requirements to do a standalone app (connect app) where you don't have to worry about the varying ways cookies are handled in iframes.  So use the CSASPNETWebsite (or better yet, the MVC one if you are up for MVC)

Comment: Pat, maybe I am confused.  Thanks for being patient with me on this one.  Here is an example: Foresquare allows you to login in their site using Facebook login (this would be then a Facebook connect app).  But, what if Facebook wants to show the same site inside facebook chrome as app, I think the same website project can be used that way, correct? In that case, when foursquare loads in the facebook chrome, the user will already be logged in if he/she is logged into facebook.